# How to get workflow id using gh workflow run cli?

Tags: github, github-actions

How to get workflow id using `gh workflow run` gh cli?

This currently is not working for me:

```
RUN_ID=$(gh workflow run workflow.yml --repo $REPO --ref $REF \
            -f param=$par| jq -r '.id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the ID from the `run` command, you need to get it after you queued it with the `list` command:

```
RUN_ID=$(gh run list --json databaseId --workflow= workflow-bot.yml --limit 1 | jq -r '.[0].databaseId')
```

The `databaseId` is the run id.

Comment: You could use -q option instead of | jq:

`RUN_ID=$(gh run list --json databaseId --workflow= workflow-bot.yml --limit 1 -q  '.[0].databaseId'`